# Duplication of enum across two models

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app, I have two classes each with the same enum for status. Code climate is complaining about duplication.

```
class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolment_presentations
  has_many :presentations, through: :enrolment_presentations

  enum status: {
    'Pending' => 1,
    'Suspended' => 2,
    'Cancelled' => 3,
    'Pass' => 4,
    'Fail' => 5,
    'DPR' => 6,
    'Unknown' => 7,
    'Enrolled' => 8
  }
end


class EnrolmentPresentations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrolment
  belongs_to :presentation

  enum status: {
    'Pending' => 1,
    'Suspended' => 2,
    'Cancelled' => 3,
    'Pass' => 4,
    'Fail' => 5,
    'DPR' => 6,
    'Unknown' => 7,
    'Enrolled' => 8
  }
end
```

How would you go about removing this duplication?

Comment: Can you can clarify this? I don't understand why an `EnrolmentPresentation` would need an independent status attribute. Shouldn't it use the associated `enrolment.status`?

Comment: You haven't explained the usage of these enums at all, as far as I'm concerned, you should just remove `status` from both classes because they are useless. Could you explain why you need them?

Comment: I don't see how you can say I should remove them because they are useless. Of course I have a usage for them, however it is not relevant, I have simplified the code to more clearly show the problem, that is duplication. Both models need a status field (this is a business requirement), the possible options/values available for the status on each model are the same. However, an Enrolment can have a status different from it's associated EnrolmentPresentations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord [enums](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) "are exposed through a class method with the pluralized attribute name", so I recommend the following code. However, I would highly recommend making the enums symbols instead of strings for compatibility. Also, enrollment is spelled with two l's. Note that you can control the capitalization of DPR using [inflections](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector/Inflections.html#method-i-acronym).

```
class Enrollment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrollment_presentations
  has_many :presentations, through: :enrollment_presentations

  enum status: {
    pending: 1,
    suspended: 2,
    cancelled: 3,
    pass: 4,
    fail: 5,
    dpr: 6,
    unknown: 7,
    enrolled: 8
  }
end

class EnrollmentPresentations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrollment
  belongs_to :presentation

  enum status: Enrollment.statuses
end
```

Comment: I've been meaning to change them to symbols (was more wondering about the duplication). Your solution of using the `Enrollment.statuses` is reasonable and I think I will go with that. Side note in US it is spelt Enrollment, UK (or outside of US) it can be spelt Enrolment :)

Answer (score 2):

Forgive my ignorance, but isn't `ActiveRecord::Base#enum` just a method? Therefore, to help *reduce* duplication (but not eliminate it), you could do something like this:

```
STATUS_FLAGS = {
  'Pending' => 1,
  'Suspended' => 2,
  'Cancelled' => 3,
  'Pass' => 4,
  'Fail' => 5,
  'DPR' => 6,
  'Unknown' => 7,
  'Enrolled' => 8
}

class Enrolment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :enrolment_presentations
  has_many :presentations, through: :enrolment_presentations

  enum status: STATUS_FLAGS
end


class EnrolmentPresentations < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :enrolment
  belongs_to :presentation

  enum status: STATUS_FLAGS
end
```

This, of course, doesn't eliminate duplication. One way around that might be to use a `module` as a mixin (though I'm not sure how that would work with `ActiveRecord`) or use singular inheritance to create a class that extends `ActiveRecord::Base` with the `enum status`, and then inherit from that - though I have to admit it feels hacky extending Active Records through inheritance.

As a stylistic note, it appears that the [convention for `#enum`](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) is to use lowercase names rather than PascalCase.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right about "convention for #enum is to use lowercase names rather than PascalCase.".
Also not a huge fan of monkey patching ActiveRecord classes. Where would STATUS_FLAGS live (i.e.  what file), for it to be available to both classes?

Comment: @mdkrog You'd put it in it's own file and `require` it, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 6, you can put the enum in a module in `concerns` and include it in your models.

*model/concerns/statusable.rb*

```
module Statusable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
        enum status: {
            pending: 1,
            suspended: 2,
            cancelled: 3,
            pass: 4,
            fail: 5,
            dpr: 6,
            unknown: 7,
            enrolled: 8
        }
    end
end
```

*model/enrollment.rb*

```
class Enrolment < ApplicationRecord
    include Statusable
    has_many :enrolment_presentations
    has_many :presentations, through: :enrolment_presentations
end
```

Comment: Can confirm this also works for Rails 5.2.3